# Targetting a specific SQS queue in AWS CloudWatch and AutoScaling

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, autoscaling

I am new to AWS AutoScaling and CloudWatch, and am using both these sdks on the windows command line. Either what I am trying to do is not possible, there is information missing from the tutorial, OR I am having a complete understanding disconnect. Help me figure out which one, please.

I have successfully set up a launch config, autoscaler, policies, and alarms relating to those policies using AWS. However, through all of the tutorials I have gone through, and examples on the web, I am have yet to see how to actually specify exactly which queue that I want my alarms to be monitoring the metrics of.

Suppose that I have several queues in the Amazon Cloud. How do I specify setting autoscaling and alarms on one of my queues and not others?

I followed these tutorials:

1. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/US_BasicSetup.html
2. Creating Policies and Alarms section in http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/as-scale-based-on-demand.html

Comment: Each queue has a name and ID: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/ImportantIdentifiers.html

Comment: Thanks for your response, Guy. I know that I can reference each queue but fetching its url. I am fine with queue identifiers. What I am unsure of is WHERE to put that queue identifier in the alarm set up command so that the alarm knows which queue to monitor the metrics of. The command to set up alarms using CloudWatch is: mon-put-metric-alarm. It has several parameters to fill in,for example alarmName, --actions-enabled, --alarm-actions, to name a few...I am unsure which of these I need to set to specify the q to monitor.

Comment: command reference: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/cli-mon-put-metric-alarm.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok.
Short answer is that you need to add to the --dimensions parameter.

```
--dimensions="QueueName=TheNameOftheQueue"
```

---

Long answer, the documentation is only partially there on their site.
Assuming you use this as a starting point:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/as-using-sqs-queue.html ,
You get to the line where you are having trouble which is:

```
prompt>mon-put-metric-alarm --alarm-name AddCapacityToProcessQueue  --metric-name ApproximateNumberOfMessagesVisible --namespace “AWS/SQS” --statistic Average --period 60 --threshold 3 --comparison-operator GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold --dimensions “AutoScalingGroupName=my-test-asg” --evaluation-periods 2 --alarm-actions arn:aws:autoscaling:us-east-1:803981987763:scalingPolicy:f4390e81-9a48-4655-ba57-f059d17799ea:autoScalingGroupName/my-test-asg:policyName/my-sqs-scaleout-policy
```

The issue being that the dimensions aren't fully filled out in their example:

```
--dimensions “AutoScalingGroupName=my-test-asg”
```

To know which dimensions this particular type of alarm might have, and that would be useful...you'd go here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/cloudwatch_concepts.html#Dimension , But...of course that only has listings for:

> Dimensions for Amazon EC2 Metrics
>
> Dimensions for Elastic Load Balancing Metrics
>
> Dimensions for RDS Metrics

This thread, https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=72613 , answers the question eventually/at the end. (And the answer is in json format, so you have to translate to command line syntax).  ie. --dimensions="keyname=keyvalue,keyname=keyvalue".

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: This did add the queue I want to the dimensions. I verified it in the CloudWatch console. There is still some strange behaviour that resulted from doing this though AND although the dimension was updated, it is not being recognized (ie, the alarm is still not going off). Also, when I run it now, I get an error on CL complaining about my metric name. Further investigation is needed. But, thank you, CasualT

Comment: You might want to try only having the "QueueName=TheName" in the dimensions, and skip including the "AutoScalingGroupName=thearg" parameter. (I think that must be a typo in the original tutorial?)